# Javascript Fetch not working as intended?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, fetch

I have got some problems with trying to fetch data from my custom ASP.Net core Rest-API. It keeps saying in the command prompt: `index.js:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`. Now I've read that this may be because I don't have CORS enabled in my backend... But I do have CORS enabled in my backend!:

```cs
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            UpdateDatabase(app);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("CorsDevelopment");

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors("CorsDevelopment").RequireAuthorization();
            });
        }
```

I've even got a configuration set up and everything!:

```cs
        public static void ConfigureCorsServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsDevelopment", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
                });
            });
        }
```

Didn't forget to configure it in services `services.ConfigureCorsServices();`.

And this is what my fetch looks like:

```js
        let options = {
            "method": "POST",
            "mode": "cors",
            "headers": {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("jwt")
            }
        };

        let query = "account/isLoggedIn";

        fetch(config.BACKEND.API_URL + query, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

Lastly the method in question:

```cs
        [HttpPost("isLoggedIn")]
        [Authorize]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(LoggedInUserViewModel), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        public IActionResult CheckIfLoggedIn()
```

I've also tried to add an `[AllowCrossSiteJson]` but also didn't work:

```cs
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

public class AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null)
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please.

**UPDATE**
It looks like while trying to fix a previous CORS issue I screwed up the backend. Is it because I configured CORS in the wrong way?

Comment: Could you share your JSON?

Comment: @Rojo the response.json()?

Comment: No, the entire JSON document, a link will be best if it is long

Comment: Look at the network panel and look what is actually returned from the server

Comment: Under the response tab it says "This request has no response data available". And is there a way to copy the json from my browser? Please specify what kind of json document because I have no idea if you're talking about network.

Comment: first, check API endpoint with Postman and confirm, is backend working?

Comment: @MUHAMMADILYAS will do right now. It keeps returning BadRequest right now, it doesn't even get into the login method with a breakpoint. It worked fine just a few hours ago.

Comment: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning NU1701 Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.`
 It keep saying this in the backend now

Comment: Based on one of your previous comment responses, your issue is that you are returning an empty response body. The response must return JSON in order for the `response.json` method to parse the body.

Comment: Yes, this isn't a front-end issue anymore. It looks like while trying to fix a previous cors issue I screwed up something in the backend

Comment: Cors issue?So what is your error message now?